# Laravel 5 add existing table from .csv

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add an existing table to my Laravel project. I'm using an Sqlite database like in Laravel from Scratch. Now I want add another table to my Sqlite database with existing data from a .csv converted excel sheet.

I edited my Sqlite DB with Sqlite Studio and added the table correctly. However, when I go into Laravel and do `DB::table('logs')->first()`, it says that there is no table with such a name.... How? Because it clearly shows it in the Sqlite studio.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I formatted a bit your question to improve readability. IMHO it'll help your question to add relevant bits of your code (e.g. the SQLite statements). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Apparently it was my sublime SFTP not uploading my database.sqlite file correctly due to the fact that you dont "save" the file. So the extension compares my version with the remote version and does not see a change. Deleting the file remotely and then uploading it again worked.

Comment: You should also really be using migrations to create tables, and seeds to populate them.